# Fortran error when I enter an input - segmentation fault

Tags: fortran

when I enter the first input I receive this error

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference. Backtrace for this error:#0  0xffffffff...

here is my code leading up to where the error occurs

```
program helloworld

implicit none

!gets inputs
character(len = :), allocatable :: point1
real :: pint1V(2)
real :: pint2V(2)
real :: pint3V(2)
character(len = :), allocatable :: point2
character(len = :), allocatable :: point3

!gets lengths
real :: length12
real :: length32
real :: length31
!gets angle of each point
real :: angle1
real :: angle2
real :: angle3 


print *, 'input point 1 as "a + bi"'
read *, point1
print *, 'input point 2 as "a + bi"'
read *, point2
print *,'input point 3 as "a + bi"'
read *, point3
```

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for point1/2/3 - that can easily cause segfault. Must be a duplicate here somewhere, will look later

Comment: But in fact what do you want point1/2/3 as allocatable? Unless you want hyper robust code (which would be somewhat more complex than you have here) I would just have them as long enough (say 132) and not have them allocatable at all

Comment: I often make them LEN=256, and then on the print/WRITE use Point1(:LEN_TRIM(Point1)). On the input it is easier as one justs get in what length they come in at.